# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1027, 8), indices imply (1030, 8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, numpy-ndarray

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('concrete_data.csv', delimiter=',', sep=r', ')
X_raw = df.drop(['concrete_compressive_strength'], axis=1)
y_raw =  df['concrete_compressive_strength']

# Isolate our examples for our labeled dataset.
n_labeled_examples = X_raw.shape[0]
training_indices = np.random.randint(low=0, high=len(X_raw)+1, size=3)

# Defining the training data
X_training = X_raw.iloc[training_indices]
y_training = y_raw.iloc[training_indices]
```

The shape of these variables are:

```
X_training.shape
```

(3, 8)

```
y_training.shape
```

(3,)

```
X_raw.shape
```

(1030, 8)

```
y_raw.shape
```

(1030,)

Now, I want to isolate the non-training examples:

```
X_pool = np.delete(X_raw, training_indices, axis=0)
y_pool = np.delete(y_raw, training_indices, axis=0)
```

This gives me the following error?

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1027, 8), indices imply (1030, 8)
```

I tried to reshape the `training_indices` but still gives the same error.

```
r = np.reshape(training_indices, (3,1), order='C')
```

May I know what is wrong, how to change the shape of `training_indices` to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use these lines:

```
X_pool = X_raw.drop(training_indices.tolist())
y_pool = y_raw.drop(training_indices.tolist())
```

instead of these lines:

```
X_pool = np.delete(X_raw, training_indices, axis=0)
y_pool = np.delete(y_raw, training_indices, axis=0)
```

Comment: @TheAfg welcome dude if you can please `upvote`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do it because I don't have enough repitution.